# Remove non-alphabetic characters from a list of lists and maintain structure

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working in python 2.7. I want to remove the non-alphabetic characters from each list in a list of lists without modifying the structure of the lists.

Starting example list of lists:

```
csvarticles = [['[Beta-blockers]', 'Magic!', '1980', 'Presse medicale'],['Hypertension in the pregnant woman].', '', '2010', 'Medical'],['Arterial hypertension.', '', '1920', 'La Nouvelle']]
print (csvarticles[0])
```

Desired Output:

> [['beta blockers', 'magic', '1980', 'presse medicale'],['hypertension in the pregnant woman', '', '2010', 'medical'],['arterial hypertension', '', '1920', 'la nouvelle']]

Code 1:

```
csvarticles = [[word.lower().split() for word in nodeList] for nodeList in csvarticles]

print (csvarticles[0])
```

Code 1 Output:

> ['[Beta-blockers]', 'Magic!', '1980', 'Presse medicale']
>   [['[beta-blockers]'], ['magic!'], ['1980'], ['presse', 'medicale']]

Code 2:

```
csvarticles = [[word.lower().split() for word in nodeList if word.isalpha()] for nodeList in csvarticles]
```

Code 2 Output:

> []

Code 3:

```
articleTitle = []
for x, y in enumerate(csvarticles):
    myString = simpleWords(csvarticles[x][0])
    if myString is not '':
        myString = myString.lower()
        myString = re.sub('[\W_]+', ' ', myString, flags=re.UNICODE)
        myList = [word for word in myString.split() if len(word) > 3]
        articleTitle = ' '.join(myList)
```

Code 3 Output:

> ['beta blockers', 'magic', '1980', 'presse medicale', 'hypertension pregnant woman', '2010', 'medical', 'arterial hypertension', '1920', 'nouvelle']

Code 3 gets close but eliminates the structure of the nested lists.

Comment: Do you still want the blank strings to be included?

Comment: The code is not valid Python.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a work request. No attempts at solving the problem are shown.

Comment: did you forget to include the condition of your list comprehension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to replace non-space or alphanum chars, and trim/lowercase the string. Regex are pretty efficient for those replacements, chained with `str.strip`.

Rebuild the nested lists in a double list comp:

```
import re

csvarticles = [['[Beta-blockers]', 'Magic!', '1980', 'Presse medicale'],['Hypertension in the pregnant woman].', '', '2010', 'Medical'],['Arterial hypertension.', '', '1920', 'La Nouvelle']]

result = [[re.sub("[^ \w]"," ",x).strip().lower() for x in y] for y in csvarticles]

print(result)
```

prints:

```
[['beta blockers', 'magic', '1980', 'presse medicale'], ['hypertension in the pregnant woman', '', '2010', 'medical'], ['arterial hypertension', '', '1920', 'la nouvelle']]
```

If you're using Python, replace `lower` by `casefold` to handle speciale locale chars

Comment: I feel like this one was right there and you submitted almost exactly the same time as @rahlf23. I'm getting an error with this: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'casefold'. If I remove casefold() is does remove the non-alpha characters correctly but does not convert to lower case.

Comment: yes, it's a python version issue. If casefold isn't available, you can use lower instead

Comment: Awesome, it works perfectly and is faster than the previous solution! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **string.isalnum()** method to check if string is either alphabet or number.

**Demo**

```
csvarticles = [['[Beta-blockers]', 'Magic!', '1980', 'Presse medicale'],['Hypertension in the pregnant woman].', '', '2010', 'Medical'],['Arterial hypertension.', '', '1920', 'La Nouvelle']]
res = []
for i in csvarticles:
    r = []
    for j in i:
        r.append("".join([k for k in j if (k.isalnum() or k.isspace())]).lower())
    res.append(r)
print(res)
```

**Output**:

```
[['betablockers', 'magic', '1980', 'presse medicale'], ['hypertension in the pregnant woman', '', '2010', 'medical'], ['arterial hypertension', '', '1920', 'la nouvelle']]
```

Comment: This is really close but eliminates spaces between the words.

Comment: Sorry I did not consider the space. Updated snippet

Comment: Yes, your solution works too! It's much slower than the one-liner provided by rahlf23, but a good solution none the less. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in a one-liner:

INPUT:

```
output = [[k.lower() for k in [' '.join(re.findall(r'[^\]\[.!-][A-z0-9]+[^\]\[.!-]', j)) for j in i]] for i in csvarticles]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[['beta blockers', 'magic', '1980', 'presse  medicale'], ['hypertension  in  the  pregnant  woman', '', '2010', 'medical'], ['arterial  hypertension', '', '1920', 'la  nouvelle']]
```

REGEX:

```
[^\]\[.!-][A-z0-9]+[^\]\[.!-]
```

Comment: This is so beautiful, works like a charm, thank you so much!